# Can a failed device that has an error loading the FPGA configuration be repaired utilizing an identical working device that works properly?

Tags: fpga

I have answered questions here before, but this is my first own question.

I purchased three ZeeVee HDb620 QAM HD modulators that were supposed to be working when removed from service, but only one of the three works.  These units are centered around an FPGA, and they attempt to boot with a correct initial sequence, but fail to fully boot. I would like to repair them because I bought them very cheap, but I am unwilling to disassemble them at this point unless there is a decent possibility that I could repair them.  Due to the fact that I can return them for a partial refund, it would be worth it for me to keep them and try to repair them if there is even a 20% chance that it is possible.

I am very well versed in logic, but not very familiar with FPGAs to the extent that I don't know if there is a way to transfer the FPGA code from the working device to the FPGAs on the failed devices.  I don't know the model of the FPGA without opening them up, so I don't know if the FPGAs are non-volatile or if they are dynamically programmed from a flash chip, etc.

I have only provided specifics of my situation to possibly narrow down any possible solutions for me, but otherwise my question stands alone for any generic device:

Can a failed device that has an error loading the FPGA configuration be repaired utilizing an identical working device that works properly?

Edit: I have JTAG, Bus Pirate, USB-Serial TTL interface, HP Logic Analyzer, etc...

Edit 2: The Verilog or VHDL code encodes MPEG2, so it will be covered by licenses for MPEG2 codec, which may be an obstacle if I would need to try to get a copy...

Thanks!

Comment: The vast majority of FPGAs are volatile and rely on external non-volatile memory elsewhere to store the configuration that is loaded into them on startup (either by the FPGA reading the non-volatile memory itself or a processor reading the NV memory and configuring the FPGA). However, these tend to be encrypted in commercial products so people can't steal the IP.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think this perfectly answers my question, and if you were to post this as a full answer, I will vote your answer as the correct one after I have had one day to see any other comments.  I did not know that it may be encrypted.  Would the encryption be done with some key in the MCU?  If the flash has been corrupted, would I be able to copy the flash from  the working unit to the other two and have them working again?

Comment: I'm not sure how the encryption works since I have never needed to use it. But encryption can be done when the FPGA reads and configures itself from the flash memory itself with no MCU intermediary. A 5 minute quick search indicates that for one method, a private key that cannot be read out of the FPGA is written to and stored in the FPGA and a public key is used to encrypt the bit file. If an MCU  is in the loop then it's probably similar.

Answer (score 2):

> These units are centered around an FPGA, and they attempt to boot with a correct initial sequence, but fail to fully boot.

An FPGA that is failing to load its configuration will usually not enter a running state.

The symptoms you're observing suggest that either:

1. The FPGA is self-configuring correctly, but is not entering a functional state afterwards for some reason (which may be caused by a hardware failure in the FPGA, or in another part of the system).
2. The boot process you are observing is driven by another controller which is failing for some reason (which may or may not involve the FPGA).

While it is *possible* that the problems you are observing are caused by a loss of FPGA configuration data, it is unlikely -- and it is even more unlikely that you will be able to successfully copy this data from another working device. If you have the option to return the devices for a refund, I'd pursue that option rather than attempting repair.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Each unit is worth at least $250 USD working used, and I only paid $50 USD each.  I would be willing(and able) to replace a faulty FPGA if it is a likely fault(I would only have to try it on one of the faulty units as a test), and/or test other components.  These are very advanced units that cost around $1000 USD new, so the thought of these being thrown in the waste bin upon return makes me cringe....